# how to use a function from another js file in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

i have a file `something.js` which has a function:

```
someFunction: function(arg1, arg2){
    //code blocks
}
```

In my `app.js` file i want to call this function in the `app` class. I have imported the `something.js` file like this `import { someFunction } from './something.js';`. Now i am trying to use it in a function in the `app` class

```
var res = someFunction("abc", 2); 
console.log(res);`
```

i am getting a error `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _something.someFunction) is not a function`

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you exported that function ? it should be like this: `export someFunction: function(arg1, arg2){
    //code blocks
}`

Comment: Yes i did like this `export default {//statements }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write it like this:

`something.js` file -

```
module.exports = {

   A: funtion(){
   },

   B: funtion(){
   }

}
```

Then import it like this:

```
import {A} from 'something';
```

Or use it like this:

`something.js` file -

```
export A(){
}

export B(){
}
```

Then import it like this:

```
import {A} from 'something';
```

Read this article: https://danmartensen.svbtle.com/build-better-apps-with-es6-modules

Comment: it is working now after i put `module.exports`. thank you

Comment: check the other way also, instead of using `module.exports` you can `export` them individually also and then you can `import` then in a same way :)

Answer (score 5):

In order to import something, you need to export it from the other module.
For example, you could `export class YourComponent extends React.Component` in something.js.

Then in the other file you can `import { YourComponent } from './something'`

You could, for example, in `something.js` do something like

```
const MyClass = {
    methodName() { return true; }
}

export { MyClass as default } // no semi-colon
```

Then in the other file you could

```
import WhateverIWant from 'something';
WhateverIWant.methodName(); // will return true
```

Edit:
An in-depth explanation with lots of examples [is available here](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html).

Comment: Yes i did like this `export default {//statements }`

Comment: It's all a queston of formatting but you do need to export anything public :) . Glad you've resolved your issue.

Comment: no no i did like this from begging but it still has the issue

Comment: I updated my answer to better cover the ES6 way as opposed to the CommonJS syntax in the other response

Answer (score 5):

You could either do: in your `something.js` file:  `module.exports = function(){}..`
and in your `app.js` file:

`const functionName = require('./path_to_your_file');`

Or `export somethingFunction = {}` and in `app.js`:

`import { somethingFunction } from './path_to_your_file'`

Or last: `export default somethingFunction = {}` and in `app.js`:

`import whateverNameYouChoose from './path_to_your_file'`

Let me know if that did the trick! :)

Comment: import {somethingFunction} from '/.path_to_your_file'

in the above line...did u mean './path_to_your_file' ??? (typo i guess :) )

Comment: Yes, it was a typo! Also corrected an incorrect part, and added another example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your `something.js` file, you can add `export someFunction` near the bottom of the file. This will then allow you to import that function using the `import { someFunction } from './something.js';` you have earlier.